# PHP current location automatically change to REQUEST_URI

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-routing

I'm using MVC. In app folder: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When access:

```
http://localhost/app/user/login
```

The $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] shows

```
/app/user/login
```

why doesn't it change to

```
/app/index.php?q=/user/login
```

When render css in login, it should load /app/style.css. But it loaded app/user/style.css which doesn't exit.

Comment: Because you are `rewriting`, not `redirecting`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix that, try completing the rest of the settings:

```
                    RewriteEngine on
                    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
                    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Here's a little extra if you want some compression with re-writes:

```
                    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
                            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
                            RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]
                            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
                            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
                            RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]
                            RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
                            RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]
                            <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
                                    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
                                    Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
                            </FilesMatch>
                    </IfModule>
```

Comment: The current location still does not work. For example after http://localhost/app/user/login success, I want to redirect to app/main by header('location: main'). It leads to app/user/main.

Comment: To redirect you just use `<?php header('Location: http://localhost/app/main'); ?>` but if you still want the file location of where you actually are, see what comes out of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and if that doesn't work try the `__FILE__` constant.  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: The $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] works nice. But I can't use `Location: http://localhost/app/main` because when access from other computer, it redirect to `http://localhost/app/main` from other computer. The only success way is `Location: ../main` but its not good.

Answer (score 0):

A RewriteRule works "below the surface". Your webserver translates the request into the URL you have set in your RewriteRule, but the URL the user has in his browser remains the same. The $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] just lists the URI the user has requested, not what it is rewritten to. But you can always get the "real URI" from your code by extracting it from your URI. Something like this would do:

```
$requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$realUri = '/app/index.php?q=' . preg_replace('/^\/app/', '', $requestUri);
```

Then `$realUri` will hold the string you are looking for.